# How to make a combo box password

Tags: vb.net

How do I make a combo box password or button password? I got this code and it does not work.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.Text = "5" Then
        If ComboBox2.Text = "3" Then
            If ComboBox3.Text = "2" Then
                If ComboBox4.Text = "6" Then
                    Button1.Enabled = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("Dony", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Dony")
    Application.Exit()
  End Sub
```

When combo box's item is 5, then it will allow the other combo box to be 3 and if the second combo box is 3 it will allow the third combo box to be 6 and if that happens it will allow the fourth combo box to be 2 and then if that happens the button is enabled.

Anyone help?

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're trying to achieve. "make a combo box password or button password" doesn't actually mean anything in and of itself. Regardless of anything else, you should learn a bit about Boolean logic, specifically the AND and OR operators.

Comment: Also telling us _it does not work_ is useless.  Tell us what you expected and  _what actually happened_.

Comment: Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your function run only when you change the selected index in your ComboBox1. Button1 will only be enabled if you choose your value for Combobox1 after you have selected all the good values for the others ComboBoxes. You should put this code in another function that you can call every time you select a value in one of your four ComboBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your code will only be executed after the first Combobox get changed. So it will only check the second, the third and the fourth position AFTER the first ComboBox get changed.

The solution for your problem is to add the other ComboBoxes as a Handler for your function. Also you listen to the wrong event. `SelectedIndexChanged` only get triggered if the user choose another answer from the list. But what if the user typed in the code? The correct event is the `TextChanged` event which also trigger the function if the user type in the code.

```
Private Sub CheckCode(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged, ComboBox2.TextChanged, ComboBox3.TextChanged, ComboBox4.TextChanged
    If ComboBox1.Text = "5" Then
        If ComboBox2.Text = "3" Then
            If ComboBox3.Text = "2" Then
                If ComboBox4.Text = "6" Then
                    Button1.Enabled = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Personally, I would not handle it that way, but it definitely solves your problem.

Comment: Marco, agree: I would change inner code to `Button1.Enabled = (Combo1.Text = "5" And Combo2.Text = "3" and Combo3.Text = "2" and Combo4.Text = "6")`. I know the `()` are not necessary, but I think it adds a level of readability to the line. Didn't want to edit your answer and not an answer in itself to the original question - feel free to add this to your answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem.

The code is

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If NumericUpDown1.Value = 5 And NumericUpDown2.Value = 3 And NumericUpDown3.Value = 2 And NumericUpDown4.Value = 6 Then
        Me.Close() 'Command here.
    End If
End Sub
```

If Anyone wants to know.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a code in other comboboxes, not only on the first one.

your code must be like this:

```
 if combobox1.text = 5 and combobox2.text = 3 and combobox3.text = 2 and combobox4.text = 6 then
 button1.enabled = true
 else
 button1.enabled = false
 endif
```

all of the comboboxes has the same code, i think. just try it :)